# USB drive is damaged from refus-2.16

Tags: usb, bios, format

I tried to make an bootable USB drive from rufus-2.16, but somehow after some action my USB drive is not recognizable from any computer.

I tried to format the drive but USB drive is not recognizable.

When I reboot the computer with F12 (BIOS setting) it does recognize the USB drive.

So is there any solution to format this drive with BIOS or low level?

Or any other options?

Comment: Do you have access to a Windows machine?

Comment: yes i can access to a window machine

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows PC, clean the USB drive as follows:

**Warning:** This will erase all data on the drive!

1. From an elevated Command Prompt run `diskpart`,
2. Type `list disk` to show all disks connected to the PC. Make note of the disk number of your USB drive.
3. Type `select disk X` (where `X` is the number of your USB drive).
4. Type `clean`

   **Warning:** This will erase all data on the selected drive!
5. Type `exit` to close diskpart

This removes all format information from the disk. You can now try Rufus again.

If you want to just return the drive to regular use, continue from step 4 above:

5. Type `create partition primary`
6. Type `select partition 1`
7. Type `active`
8. Type `format FS=NTFS label=USBDrive quick`
9. Type `assign`
10. Type `exit` to close diskpart

These last commands will create a partition on the drive and format it.